# a line contains strings,separated by ','

Tags: python

in Python, trying to do this thing:
I have a line contains several strings separated by ','.
I want to erase every string that has particular substring in it.
for example:

```
line: first_name,second_name,every_single_name_exicted,dog,cat.
```

I want to erase every string that has the word "name" in it + the ',' it has, so the result would be:

```
line: dog,cat.
```

and not:

```
line: ,,,dog,cat
```

what can I use to achieve that? 
and how generally can I search particular substring when I don't care what it has on its left or right (like the search option in NotePad for example when you can write *name*)

Comment: `split(',')` the string to give you a list, and use `in` on each substring to check for your match

Comment: That's a [Comma-Separated Values (or CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) input. And there are Python modules which are written to handle such specifically, especially since attempting to parse such data on your own is non-trivial because there are some very hard corner-cases.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like that a sensible combination of `split()` and `join()` with a conditional list comprehension would do the trick here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm fond of the csv module which is great to process complex files, but for simple operations `str.split` or `re.split` can make sense...

Comment: As for your problem, it's very easy when using Python lists. See e.g. [here for a list of operations on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). I'm sure you'll be able to find what you need quite quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = 'first_name,second_name,every_single_name_exicted,dog,cat'

s = s.split(',')
a = ','.join([i for i in s if 'name' not in i])
print(a)
```

Try this

Comment: great thank you very much it works!
just a little problem, it leaves a lot of spaces in the places we removed the 'name'.
what causing that?

Comment: `dog,cat` is the output I am getting. What spaces are you talking about?

Comment: @ValentinaNikolenko: See my answer for this.

Comment: I don't see no harm throwing this all in one line, readability doesn't seem to bad  `s = ','.join([i for i in s.split(',') if 'name' not in i])
`

Answer (score 0):

- split the string with .split(",")
- Filter by "name" with `if not in`.
- strip leading / trailing whitespace with .strip()
- join the string with ", ".join()
- Add a dot at the end of the string if necessary with + "."

Like this:

```
 mystring = "first_name,  second_name, every_single_name_exicted,dog,cat"

 newstring = ", ".join(s.strip() for s in mystring.split(",") if not "name" in s) + "."
```